# sqlite and 'constraint failed' error while select and insert at the same time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working on migration function. It reads data from old table and inserts it into the new one. All that stuff working in background thread with low priority.

My steps in pseudo code.

```
sqlite3_prepare_stmt (select statement)
sqlite3_prepare_stmt (insert statement)

while (sqlite3_step (select statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    get data from select row results
    sqlite3_bind select results to insert statement
    sqlite3_step (insert statement)
    sqlite3_reset (insert statement)
}

sqlite3_reset (select statement)
```

I'm always getting 'constraint failed' error on `sqlite3_step (insert statement)`. Why it's happend and how i could fix that?

**UPD:** As i'm understand that's happend because background thread use db handle opened in main thread. Checking that guess now.

**UPD2:**

```
sqlite> select sql from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'tiles';
CREATE TABLE tiles('pk' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'data' BLOB, 'x' INTEGER, 'y' INTEGER, 'z' INTEGER, 'importKey' INTEGER)
sqlite> select sql from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'tiles_v2';
CREATE TABLE tiles_v2 (pk int primary key, x int, y int, z int, layer int, data blob, timestamp real)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It probably means your insert statement is violating a constraint in the new table. Could be a primary key constraint, a unique constraint, a foreign key constraint (if you're using `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`), and so on.

You fix that either by dropping the constraint, correcting the data, or dropping the data. Dropping the constraint is usually a Bad Thing, but that depends on the application.

Is there a compelling reason to copy data one row at a time instead of as a set?

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT column_list FROM old_table;
```

If you need help identifying the constraint, edit your original question, and post the output of these two SQLite queries.

```
select sql from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'old_table_name';
select sql from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'new_table_name';
```

---

**Update:** Based on the output of those two queries, I see only one constraint--the primary key constraint in each table. If you haven't built any triggers on these tables, the only constraint that can fail is the primary key constraint. And the only way that constraint can fail is if you try to insert two rows that have the same value for 'pk'.

I suppose that could happen in a few different ways.

- The old table has duplicate values in
  the 'pk' column.
- The code that does your migration
  alters or injects a duplicate value
  before inserting data into your new
  table.
- Another process, possibly running on
  a different computer, is inserting or
  updating data without your knowledge.
- Other reasons I haven't thought of yet. :-)

You can determine whether there are duplicate values of 'pk' in the old table by running this query.

```
select pk 
from old_table_name
group by pk
having count() > 1;
```

You might consider trying to manually migrate the data using `INSERT INTO . . . SELECT . . .` If that fails, add a WHERE clause to reduce the size of the set until you isolate the bad data.

Comment: no. i'm not using foreign_keys. and there is another thread that perform inserts successfully. now i'm even fill insert always with the same data. and situation didn't changes. second thread is always failed to insert data. inserts guarded by mutexes so only one possible in one time.

Comment: Added directions for extracting the SQL DDL from SQLite. Edit your original question, and insert the results of those two queries.

Comment: in UPD i added that i'm trying to execute insert with the same data in 2 threads many times. First thread (where sqlite3 * was opened) works always fine, insert in second one didn't work. as you can see from table schemas - pk is unique in both tables.

Comment: You can isolate the problem to application code by running `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT column_list FROM old_table;` manually from the sqlite prompt. If it succeeds, the problem is in your application code; if it fails, the problem is in the database. If the problem's in application code, you should reduce it to the least code that reproduces the problem, edit your original question, and include that code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There was a really stupid bug with setting a new primary key.

Comment: One great thing about programming--it keeps you humble. Me, I've been humble since 1985.

Comment: If you're hitting this with check constraints, try naming the check constraints; that makes it much easier to find out what's going wrong. If only that also worked for foreign key failures...

Answer (score 3):

I have found that troubleshooting foreign key constraint errors with sqlite to be troublesome, particularly on large data sets.   However the following approach helps identify the offending relation.

1. disable foreign key checking: `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0;`
2. execute the statement that cause the error - in my case it was an INSERT of 70,000 rows with 3 different foreign key relations.
3. re-enable foreign key checking: `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;`
4. identify the foreign key errors:  `PRAGMA foreign_key_check(table-name);`

In my case, it showed the 13 rows with invalid references.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone lands here looking for "Constraint failed" error message, make sure your `Id` column's type is `INTEGER`, not `INTEGER (0, 15)` or something.

**Background**

If your table has a column named `Id`, with type `INTEGER` and set as Primary Key, SQLite treats it as an alias for the built-in column `RowId`. This column works like an auto-increment column. In my case, this column was working fine till some table designer (probably the one created by SQLite guys for Visual Studio) changed column type from `INTEGER` to `INTEGER (0, 15)` and all of a sudden my application started throwing `Constraint failed` exception.

Answer (score 1):

just for making it more clearer : 

make sure that you use data type correct , i was using `int` instead of `integer` on creating tmy tables like this :

`id int primary key not null`

and i was **stuck** on the constrain problem over hours ... 
just make sure that to enter data type correctly in creating database.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that this error occurs is inserting duplicated data for a unique row too. Check your all unique and keys for duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

Today i had similar error: `CHECK constraint failed: profile`

First i read [here](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-constraint.php#Constraint) what is constraint.

> The CONSTRAINTS are an integrity which defines some conditions that
> restrict the column to contain the true data while inserting or
> updating or deleting. We can use two types of constraints, that is
> column level or table level constraint. The column level constraints
> can be applied only on a specific column where as table level
> constraints can be applied to the whole table.

Then figured out that i need to check how database was created, because i used sqlalchemy and sqlite3 dialect, i had to check tables `schema`. Schema will show actual database structure.

```
sqlite3 >>> .schema
CREATE TABLE profile (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    ...
    forum_copy_exist BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false', 
    forum_deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'true', 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (id), 
    UNIQUE (login_name), 
    UNIQUE (forum_name), 
    CHECK (email_verified IN (0, 1)), 
    UNIQUE (uid), 
    CHECK (forum_copy_exist IN (0, 1)), 
    CHECK (forum_deleted IN (0, 1))
```

So here I found that boolean CHECK is always 0 or 1 and i used column default value as 'false', so each time i had no forum_copy_exist or forum_deleted value, false was inserted, and because false is invalid value it throws error, and didn't inserted row.

So changing database defaults to:

```
forum_copy_exist BOOLEAN DEFAULT '0', 
forum_deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT '0',
```

solved the issue.

In postgresql i think false is valid value. So it depends how database schema is created.

Hope this will help others in the future.

Comment: `'false'` is a string while `false` is equal to `0` in SQLite.

Comment: `bool = db.Column(db.Boolean, server_default=False)` in sqlalchemy is impossible to ad False to Boolean column, only 0 or 1 is working

Comment: There is no Boolean data type in SQLite even if you define a column as such. SQLite considers `false` as `0` and `true` as `1`. The problem that you had is incorrect definition of the default values of the columns. When you set `'false'` as the default value this means that you store the string value `'false'` in the column when you don't supply a value for this column in the `INSERT` statement. This string has nothing to do with the boolean value `false`.

Comment: Ok thx, that make sense, but is imposible to add false to sqlalchemy column, if you use `false` python interprets as namespace value, if you use `'false'` for sqlite is wrong for postgresql is valid (not tested) also `'f'` is valid for postgresql, anyway safest is `bool = db.Column(db.Boolean, server_default='0')`, from what i tested.

Comment: I just found how to set true or false properly in sqlalchemy `from sqlalchemy.sql import expression` and `server_default=expression.false()` rightt now i cant test it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **INTEGER** as **INT** on the referencing table, and **INTEGER** in the referenced table for the foreign key. The thing is that you need to use INTEGER in both places. Be consistent. So using INTEGER in both cases, solved my problem. *Now it runs like magic.*